# Clearing GPU memory after interrupting the script

Tags: pytorch

I noticed that when I break a program multiple times (written in Pytorch with cuda enabled), the GPU memory does not get flushed. Is there any way to do it in such instances when the script needs to be interrupted several times without finishing its execution?

Comment: Do you mean suspending it with say *CTRL + Z*? If so, that would require to transfer all GPU data to CPU and when resuming to transfer everything back. That is infeasible since the suspension can happen at any given time, making it impossible to restore the exact state later, because everything needs to be in the exact same memory location or you'd need to modify all internal references.

Comment: I do not mean to restore it later. I would just rerun the script from the beginning. The thing is though that after a few times when I break the program (`Ctrl`+`c`), the GPU is running out of memory.